# Quiero hacer un textarea que tenga una parte modificable y otra no modificable

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Deseo crear una `textarea` dentro de una forma hecha en `HTML`, usando simple `CSS` en la que puedo ver una información que ya he introducido y después dentro del mismo `textarea` poder agregar texto.

Logre hacer algo parecido usando 2 `textarea` pero se ve tan bien y en modo dinámico queda muy mal parado.

Esto es lo que tengo

```css
.var {
  margin-top: -15px;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Textarea with Fixed Text Portion</legend>
    <textarea readonly="readonly" cols="50" rows="2">This part of the textarea content is fixed and cannot be changed</textarea> `introducir el código aquí`<br/>
    <textarea class="var" cols="50" rows="10">but the rest of the textarea content can be changed to whatever you want.</textarea>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Lo que pides no es posible hacerlo con css3, quiza si con js

Comment: Desafortunadamente los textarea no cuentan con funcionalidad como la que ocupas, donde puedas agregar etiquetas HTML dentro del texto del input y aplicarle estilos css (disabled, display, color, etc), Este ejemplo es lo más cercano a lo que ocupas, donde simulas un text area dentro de un div y adentro de este puedes agregar etiquetas HTML y aplicar estilos, pero no es un método recomendado, te debo la explicación porque aquí el artículo que quería leer está bloqueado de la red. http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/XNkDx/

Comment: Gracias voy a ver si hay algun metodo, no estoy cerrado a JavaScript/ Jquery/ angular o bootstrap pero necesito solucionar este detalle.GRACIAS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directamente sobre un TextArea no es posible por ningin medio, lo que se puede hacer es "emular" un text area con un div editable, te pongo un ejemplo rápido

```js
function send(){
var valor = "";
$("#ta > .row").each(function(){
  valor += this.innerHTML + "\r\n";
});
console.log("Valor del TextArea: ");
console.log(valor);
}

function editar(textArea){
$(textArea).children("[contenteditable='true']").focus();
}
```

```css
.simulatextarea {border: 1px #CCC solid; padding: 3px;}
.simulatextarea .row {height: 18px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ta" class="simulatextarea" onclick="editar(this)">
  <div class="row" contenteditable="true"> </div>
  <div class="row" >Texto fijo</div>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="send();" value="Enviar" />
```